# Ckeditor how to apply keyboard shortcut to a particular style

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, wysiwyg, fckeditor

Is it possible to apply a keyboard shortcut to a particular style from Styles drom down in CkEditor? I searched their docs but I could not find a solution for my case.

Here is screenshot.

[image]

Here I want to be able to apply a keyboard shortcut to yellow marker from that Styles drop down. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/S3MY6/3/). This example shows how to attach a style to `CTRL+SHIFT+1` keystroke.
You can use switch statement for different keystrokes and play with them any way you want.

Comment: It would be great if you could help with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426679/ckeditor-how-to-create-custom-styles-drop-down