# CKEditor how to create custom styles drop down?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, fckeditor

Is there any way to create custom Styles drop down in Ckeditor?

Screenshot:

[image]

As can be seen in screenshot, I want to be able to create a new dropdown (like Styles dropdown) to contain these yellow and green markers and possibly others that I want.

I have seen docs but they only show how to create custom buttons to add to toolbar but I dont know how to add a custom dropdown with styles to toolbar.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you will need to create a plugin to make this work.  An example can be found here:
http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/Custom-drop-down

Additionally there seems to be addOn for CKeditor located here:
http://ckeditor.com/addon/strinsert

This addOn adds strings to your content but you may be able to look at the code and figure how to make it add stylings.