# How to configure shortcut keys in CK EDITOR 4. Not finding Plugin for Keystrocks

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, fckeditor

I want to disable some key in CK EDITOR.

I am using CKEDITOR 4.0 & I want to disable some shortcuts keys in CKEDITOR.

e.g. help file opens on Alt + 0

In old version Config Available in Source/plugins/keystroks/plugins.js But not availble in new version.

Comment: Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423734/ckeditor-how-to-apply-keyboard-shortcut-to-a-particular-style

Comment: I want to remove existing shortcut. It is for adding shortcut.

Comment: Editing Source/plugins/keystroks/plugins.js was a bad idea. The correct way to change such values is to use the config.js file, not the source files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`config.keystrokes`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-keystrokes) you can add and remove keystrokes.

From documentation:

```
// Disable default CTRL + L keystroke which executes link command by default.
config.keystrokes = [
    ...
    [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 76, null ],                       // CTRL + L
    ...
];
```

Comment: Thank, But I want general config in source So changes May be applicable to all CK Editor. I don't need to configure all individual CK Editor.

Answer (score 3):

Replace the [CKEditor.config.keystrokes](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.keystrokes) with an empty array:

```
CKEDITOR.config.keystrokes = [];
```

Or CKeditor already offers a hotkey functionality (see the CKeditor documentation). Using this functionality we can bind keystrokes to CKeditor actions. In order to save, the following line should be added:

`CKEDITOR.config.keystrokes = ... [ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 83 /*S*/, null ], ...`

Comment: Thank, But I want general config in source So changes May be applicable to all CK Editor. I don't need to configure all individual CK Editor.

Comment: CKEDITOR.config.keystrokes is initially undefined, is that expected?

Answer (score 1):

I see you have comments on both answers asking about applying changes to all CKEditor instances. The following code should allow you to override settings for all instances

```
window.onload = function(){
    CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (ev) {
        ev.editor.setKeystroke(CKEDITOR.ALT + 48 /*0*/, false);
    });
}
```

Every time a CKEDITOR instance is initialized and ready, it will automatically disable alt+0.

There is a list of the ascii codes for the different characters here for reference if you want to disable other keys: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters

Use the number in the Dec (decimal) column to disable they key in the Glyph column.