# Keyevent on an active textarea(ckeditor) in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

I have the code below

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  //function showChar(){
    shortcut.add("Ctrl+F1", function() 
      document.activeElement.id.value +="text";
  });
  var counter=0;
    setInterval(function() {
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
                var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);
                newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<div><label style="float:left;"></label></div><pre><textarea name="textbox' + counter + '" id="textbox"  ><%=rsta2.getString("data")%></textarea></pre>');
                newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
                counter++;
                }
CKEDITOR.replace( 'textbox'+i+'',
                    {
                toolbar :
                    [
                        ['Source'],
                        ['Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike'],
                    ],
                        height: 300,
                        width: 700
                    });  


    },1000);
 });
</script>
<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
  <div id="TextBoxDiv0">
  </div>
  </div>
```

The above code(minus the ckeditor part of the code) adds 4 textareas,depending on which textarea is active when I press `ctrl+f1` `text` is added to that particular textarea.But when I replace textarea with ckeditor the shortcut keys dont work.What should I do?

**UPDATE**
This is the closest I have got.The Jfiddle is below

http://jsfiddle.net/S3MY6/45/

Here I can add text to only 1 editor provider I specify the id,But I want to add it to the active one.So I had tried this

```
var xy=CKEDITOR.currentInstance.name;
     //alert(xy);
 xy.insertText('html here.');
```

But it threw an error saying object editor1 has no insertTest().But when I alert xy I get the proper editor id/name.
Please help

**UPDATE2**

I have got it to work right now with this JFiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/S3MY6/49/

But I get snapshot shortcut also along with it.I just want to add text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your updated fiddle i replaced `var xy=CKEDITOR.instances.editor1` with `var xy=CKEDITOR.currentInstance` and it worked.

http://jsfiddle.net/8mVM3/

Comment: Thnx alot,was struggling for many days.Instead of 1 how do I put F1?

Comment: And instead of ckeditor.ctrl,is it possible to use ascii keys?

Comment: that's another question, i'm not your personal consultant! try doing it, if you absolutely can't, open another question.

Answer (score 0):

My [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20581720/ckeditor-and-display-users-data-as-they-type/20610920#20610920) will help you understand why the value of `textarea` has no impact on what you see in CKEditor and how to deal with it.

Anyway, I'm sure you will find [`editor.insertHtml()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-insertHtml) (and `insertText`) helpful for your task.

Comment: could you provide me a jfiddle example with editor.insertHtml().Please.It would be of great help .I saw this post of yours,but canI I add text also to this?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423734/ckeditor-how-to-apply-keyboard-shortcut-to-a-particular-style

Comment: I have updated my question..please have a look at it